# Error running unit tests after upgrading to TFS 2015 v3

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfs-2015

I have unit tests that get executed as part of my **TFS 2015** build (created using the native **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting** assembly).

Everything worked fine. I upgraded TFS this morning to **TFS 2015 v3**. The upgrade went perfectly and no errors were encountered.

Running a subsequent build and the unit tests are no longer getting executed. I run these using a Visual Studio Test build step.

Looking into the build logs I have found that there are subtly different commands being executed for vstest.console.exe.

A working command (from yesterday before the upgrade)

```
vstest.console.exe
"E:\TfsData\Build\_work\DEV\CoreLibraryTests\bin\Release\CoreLibraryTests.dll"  
/Settings:"E:\TfsData\Build\_work\DEV\CoreLibraryTests\CoreLibraryTests.runsettings" 
/logger:trx
```

And here's one from today (that fails)

```
vstest.console.exe 
"$/DEV/CoreLibraryTests/bin/Release/CoreLibraryTests.dll"  
/Settings:"E:\TfsData\Build\_work\DEV\CoreLibraryTests\CoreLibraryTests.runsettings" 
/logger:trx
```

In the failing build step the path "*$/DEV/CoreLibraryTests/bin/Release/CoreLibraryTests.dll*" has not been resolved to a physical path on disk (which it did previously - see working command).

This was all working and I can't understand why it's now failing. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you lost your workspace mappings?

Comment: @AggieEric Where would I need to check to see if the workspace mappings have been lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **update** the build agent in Agent Pools which you are using and try again.

If this still not work, try to create a new build definition with the same settings as a workaround. The issue should go away.

---

### Update

How to update build agent

Open your web portal (such as `http://your server:8080/tfs`)-open the **control panel** (click account settings icon on the top right corner)- select **agent pools** -right click the agent pool you are using and select **update all agents**.

[image]

How to check the workspace mappings

Open Visual Studio- Click the Triangle symbol beside your workspace - In the pop up **Manage workspace** window select **edit** - double check the mapping relationships between source control folder and local folder should still exist.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for.